# Arrayformula for the Data Validation and if function

Tags: arrays, validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Action item tab:
Column A - Score - is based on calculations from the columns F-N

I want to assess the score according to the following range and assign the task in column B from a drop down menu.

Minor update    89-50
Localize        49-20
Major update    49-20
Merge           49-20
No action item  90-100
Redirect        0-19

It is important to keep the dropdown menu since the data is going to be checked manually and the status might be changed.

So generally speaking, I want to implement 2 steps:

1. Automatically to range the data and assign the status
2. To have the possibility to change the status manually.

I tried to implement it through Data Validation and simply failed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WsnAQPrrL2o4me55ghVaQHx2ZE9aisgbEIDtG6HQFn4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you said:

*I want to assess the score according to the following range and assign the task in column B from a drop down menu.*

When would that assessment and assignment happen?  That is, what would trigger it initially?  Entering a value in column D?  Changing the data on the extracted data tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, three of your ranges are conflicting, it will still work but will always get the first one which is "Localize". You should update the ranges for **Localize**, **Major update** and **Merge** so they don't have conflicting ranges.

#### Conflict:

[image: Localize Major update Merge]

#### Formula (A4):

```
=ifs(and(A4 < 90, A4 >= 50), "Minor update", 
and(A4 < 50, A4 >= 20), "Localize", 
and(A4 < 50, A4 >= 20), "Major update", 
and(A4 < 50, A4 >= 20), "Merge", 
and(A4 <= 100, A4 >= 90), "No action item", 
and(A4 < 20, A4 >= 0), "Redirect")
```

Just drag the formula onto the cells below (e.g A5-A9). I am not using `Arrayformula` as it will fail if you modify a cell within its range.

#### Output:

[image: output1]

#### Modifying F5 and G5 (Extracted data) to 0:

[image: ouptut2]

#### Note:

- You can have formula on top of your Data Validations
- I modified your Data Validations for column B into from `=Legend!$A$2:$B$7` to `=Legend!$A$2:$A$7` since we only need the action items, not the range.
- You can still manually change your column B values **BUT** it won't automatically update ever again after manually changing it unless you copy the formula again to that cell and it will overwrite your manual input and go back to automatically updating based on the column F-N values.
- These changes were already applied to your sheet, kindly check if it meets your expected output.

Comment: thank you very much! My bad, Localize, Major Update, Merge - with the same number. I would like to keep 49-20 range as simply blank and incorporate array formula. That means what is blank, will have to be corrected manually.

Comment: You're welcome @Hanna. If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)